# Any tool or tip for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V as single key?

Tags: microsoft-word

Are there any easy tool which will do both the functions of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?

We have a series of front end screens from the customer (say 100) for multiple applications and we have to take the screen shots of some in particular. To do so, we always use the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste in a Word document. But, we want to avoid this and use a single key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or some thing else). When we press the key, the screen should be auto updated in a Word doc.

Answer (score 0):

If those are separate image files then just **select all of them then drag-and-drop** to the Word document. You can also select *Insert > Image* and select all of them

Copying all of them then paste to Word should also work

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to reprogram some keys.

To make screenshots I use the free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) image viewer where you can set a key to make it save screenshots to a folder (in the menu under Options - Capture/Screenshot). You can even tell it to capture just the active windows and to include ot exclude the mouse pointer.

To import multiple images in Word or PowerPoint you can import all image files at once.